# Cant access the session from another route

Tags: node.js, session, express

Im using [client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) and this is my code:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{

    if (!req.session.activeUser){
        User.findOne({username:req.body.username}).then(doc=>{
            req.session.activeUser = req.body.username
            res.send(req.session.activeUser + " Logged in successfully")
        }).catch(e=>{
            res.send(e)
        })
    }else {
        res.redirect("/")
    }

})

app.get("/logout", (req, res)=>{
        req.session.reset()
        res.redirect("/")
})

app.get("/online", (req, res)=>{
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.session))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session))
})
```

The response of `/login` works well, but the controller `/online` returns an empty object.

I've tried [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and got the same problem

Here's my configuration:

```
app.use(sessions({
    cookieName: "session",
    secret: "root",
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the  cookieName property is set to 'session'  in your sessions global middleware.

Comment: Im pretty damn sure

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to check the "require" part maybe you had misspelled the session.

Comment: I've implemented the package on the top of the file

Comment: i can see u r using  "sessions" not "session" so check again @BaHaaJr

Comment: Sessions is the name of the package since session is the name of the cookie